# Launch Excel file from Python on Mac

Tags: python, excel, macos, file, path

I'd like to start an Excel file from Python on a Mac. When I hardcode the file path like in the following lines it works fine.

```
import os
os.system("open -a 'Microsoft Excel.app' 'path/file.xlsx'")
```

But the problem is that instead of hardcoding the path my solution should look something like:

```
file_path = '/Users/path/file.xlsx'  
import os  
os.system("open -a'Microsoft Excel.app' 'file_path'")
```

Apparently this does not work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this maybe:

os.system("open -a 'Microsoft Excel.app' '%s'" % file_path)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting to insert the value of `file_path` into the command. If you're using Python 3, it's recommended to use the [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) syntax, for example:

```
import os
file_path = "/Users/path/file.xlsx"
os.system(f"open -a 'Microsoft Excel.app' '{file_path}'")
```

For more information, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples.